# Infinite loop when using filter with specific url pattern

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting an infinite loop with my filter. The url-pattern is not generic. I can't seem to figure why it is causing that. Here is the mapping for my filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AdminAuthentication</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.filters.AdminAuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AdminAuthentication</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/addLocation</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/admin/deleteLocation</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This code is executed before `chain.doFilter(request, response)`

```
private void doBeforeProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (debug) {
        log("AdminAuthFilter:DoBeforeProcessing");
    }

HttpServletRequest _request = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
    HttpSession session = _request.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); 

    if(user == null) {
        //send redirect somewhere
        HttpServletResponse _response = (HttpServletResponse) response; 
        _response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); 
        return; 
    }
}
```

My problem is when I go to admin/addLocation without logging in I get an infinite redirect like so 
`http://localhost:8080/PROJ/admin/admin/admin/admin...` otherwise it works fine when I do login. The login.jsp is also not in the admin folder. Please help.

Comment: What is inside your `<filter></filter>` tag in the DD?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav Sorry, didn't think it was needed. The question is edited.

Comment: Can you use `RequestDispatcher` instead of `sendDirect()` ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: There is nothing bad with using the `sendRedirect()`;

Comment: @user1729869: Can you make sure, your method `doBeforeProcessing()` is called from inside the overriden `doFilter()` method.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav I'm sure it is. The partial implementation of the class is generated by Netbeans. All I had to do was insert my code in the `doBeforeProcessing()` method.

Comment: @user1729869: Try to print something in the server log in the `if(user==null){}` block to check if the request is being redirected or not. Also change the `login.jsp` to the actual `url` of the page, because it will currently look inside the `admin` folder for the `login.jsp` file.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav When I put in `log("here")` inside the `if(user == null)` It prints once (I was expecting it to print more than once). Also, I added the following change for the redirection  `_response.sendRedirect(filterConfig.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");` is that what you meant ? I noticed two things: if I start my application by running a file inside the admin folder I get the problem but If I start it with any file outside the admin folder and then type a url for a page inside the admin folder the redirection works. Is this normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entry point needs to be outside of your filter.  Your redirect is prob. fighting the chain.doFilter due to the fact user is null.

Here is a simple login filter I use to check if the user is logged in and in the session within the defined url pattern.

Filter descriptor

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AdminFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.AdminLoginFilter</filter-class>
    <description>Admin Login Filter</description>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Admin_login_form</param-name>
        <param-value>/administration/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AdminFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/administration/controlpanel/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Servlet Filter

```
public class AdminLoginFilter implements Filter {

private FilterConfig filterConfig;
private String loginForm; 

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    loginForm = this.filterConfig.getInitParameter("Admin_login_form");
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();

    ControlPanelUser adminUser = (ControlPanelUser) session.getAttribute(PageConstants.CONTROL_PANEL_USER); 

    if ((adminUser == null || adminUser.getBoId() < 1)) { //Send user to login form
        filterConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(loginForm).forward(request, response); 
    } else {// Send user to requested page
        chain.doFilter(request,response); 
    }

}

public void destroy() {
    this.filterConfig = null;
}
}
```

Credential check

```
public class CheckUserCredentialsCommand implements Command {
public void execute(CommandContext commandContext) throws Exception {

    ILoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.populateFromForm(commandContext);

    List<ValidationMessage> messages = loginForm.validate();

    if(messages != null && messages.size() > 0){
        commandContext.setScopedVariable(PageConstants.LOGIN_MESSAGES, messages, ScopedContext.REQUEST);
    } else {        
        ControlPanelUser customer = ControlPanelUserDAO.selectControlPanelUser(loginForm.getEmailAddress(), loginForm.getPasswrd());
        if(customer != null){
            commandContext.setScopedVariable(PageConstants.CONTROL_PANEL_USER, customer, ScopedContext.SESSION);
        } else {
            commandContext.setScopedVariable(PageConstants.LOGIN_MESSAGES, messages, ScopedContext.REQUEST);
        }
    }
    String referer = commandContext.getRequest().getHeader("referer");
    if(referer != null){
        referer = referer.substring(referer.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, referer.length());
        if("login".equals(referer)){
            commandContext.redirect(commandContext.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/administration/controlpanel/dashboard");
        } else {
            commandContext.redirect(commandContext.getRequest().getHeader("referer"));
        }
    } else {
        commandContext.redirect(commandContext.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/administration/controlpanel/dashboard");
    }
}

}
```

my login entry is http://www.mysite.com/administration/login, when i login on that page it submits to the CheckUserCredentialsCommand which is just a simple servlet.  That servlet then tries to do a page redirect to one of the pages that is behind the filter.  In the filter it checks the user, if the user is null it forwards back to the login page, if there is a valid user it goes through the filter chain which was your redirect from the CheckUserCredentialsCommand and now your ur l looks like http://www.mysite.com/administration/controlpanel/dashboard, dashboard page being behind the filter, if there was no user you would never be able to get to that page.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure I understand what you mean by "Your entry point needs to be outside of your filter". My login.jsp form is outside of the admin folder. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: The url for the login page in my example is configured here:

    <init-param>
        <param-name>Admin_login_form</param-name>
        <param-value>/administration/login</param-value>
    </init-param>

Now the url pattern for all pages that should be evaluated by the filter is here:
<url-pattern>/administration/controlpanel/*</url-pattern>
So my login page is http://127.0.0.1:8080/administration/login which then if there is a user forwards to another servlet that does some work then finally redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8080/administration/contropanel/.......

Comment: Check out my updated example

Comment: So in summary the only time you would ever run code in that filter is if your url was www.mysite.com/administration/controlpanel/.....
[
www.mysite.com/administration/login should never hit that filter code, this is your entry point that should be outside the mapped filter url pattern. ]

Comment: After taking a closer look at your code I managed to find many flaws in mines and I decided to rewrite my filter. Thank you VERY much for providing this sample code and your walkthrough.